# sql query to combine two records with same id

Tags: sql-server

I have created a query to calculate PO Quantity and SO Quantity. The problem is that for SO quantity i get two rows for same product with different SO quantity. What i want to do is add the SO quantity for the same products and display it as a single row in database.Please advise.

Following is the query i have written:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.ProductCode,
                products.ProductName,
                pe.stockreorderqty,
                pe.stocklowqtyalarm,
                products.StockStatus,
                pe.lastpo_qty,
                pe.lastpo_date,
                pe.vendor_price,
                Sum(PO_Items.POI_Quantity) - Sum(PO_Items.POI_QtyReceived) AS OutstandingPOQty,
                orderdetails.Quantity as outstandingsoqty
FROM Products INNER JOIN Products_Extended pe WITH (NOLOCK) ON products.ProductID = pe.ProductID 
LEFT JOIN PO_Items ON products.ProductCode = PO_Items.POI_ProductCode
LEFT JOIN orderdetails 
INNER JOIN orders ON orderdetails.OrderID = orders.OrderID  ON orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode 
    AND orders.OrderStatus <>'Cancelled' 
    AND orders.OrderStatus <>'Shipped'
    AND orders.OrderStatus <>'Returned'
GROUP BY products.ProductCode, products.ProductName, pe.stockreorderqty,
         pe.stocklowqtyalarm, products.StockStatus, pe.lastpo_qty,
         pe.lastpo_date, pe.vendor_price, orderdetails.Quantity
```

The output i get for the query is following:

```
productcode
productname
stockreorderqty
stocklowqtyalarm
stockstatus
lastpo_qty
lastpo_date
vendor_price
outstandingpoqty
outstandingsoqty
10195
Carclo 19° Frosted 20mm Lens - No Holder
0
5
120
300
06/16/11 09:32 PM
1.05
0
50

Carclo 19° Frosted 20mm Lens - No Holder
0
5
120
300
06/16/11 09:32 PM
1.05
0
56
```

in the above output the product codes are same only the outstandingsoqty is different. I want to add the outstandingsoqty and display two rows as one single row.
 they have different outstandingsoqty for same product code as it is for different open sales order.

You can check the image for output at the following link:
http://qedlr.fhmto.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/queryresult.png

Comment: You might get a better response if you format the sql, output and give an example of the desired output

Comment: Use GROUP BY, and SUM the quantities.

Comment: if i sum the outstandingsoqty  i get two different rows for same productcode. Only the numbers in the outstandingsoqty changes.

Comment: Sum `orderdetails.Quantity`, and remove it from GROUP BY

Comment: when i sum it i get wrong quantity. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to to this. Don't use Group by where you are expecting large result set, it will make your query slow, Instead use sub-query.

Do this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [OTHER Fields], 
(SELECT Sum(PO_Items.POI_Quantity) - Sum(PO_Items.POI_QtyReceived) FROM PO_Items WHERE PO_Items.POI_ProductCode = products.ProductCode) as OutstandingPOQty,
(SELECT Sum(det1.Quantity) FROM orderdetails AS det1 WHERE det1.productcode =products.productcode and det1.OrderID=orders.OrderID) as outstandingsoqty
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN Products_Extended pe WITH (NOLOCK) ON products.ProductID = pe.ProductID 
LEFT JOIN orderdetails INNER JOIN orders ON orderdetails.OrderID = orders.OrderID ON orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode 
and orders.OrderStatus <>'Cancelled' and orders.OrderStatus <>'Shipped' and orders.OrderStatus <>'Returned'
```

It will be pretty fast. Hope it helps.

Comment: i want the outstandingsoqty to be the sum of quantity where orders.OrderStatus <>'Cancelled' and orders.OrderStatus <>'Shipped' and orders.OrderStatus <>'Returned' . Please advise. now it is giving me sum of all order quantities

Comment: Add **det1.OrderID=orders.OrderID** in outstandingsoqty sub-query. Revised query accordingly

Comment: Give me the results you are getting, so that I can rectify.

Comment: for example for product code 10507 i am getting two records with outstandingsoqty 1 for the first record and 2 for second record